# stopContinuousRecognitionAsync function does not stop the session

Tags: azure, speech-to-text

I am trying to start and stop speech to text on the click of a button.
I was able to start the session but Stopping the session was not working as intended.

```
const onStopRecordHandler = () => {
    recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync(
      function () {
        recognizer.close();
        recognizer = undefined;
      },
      function (err) {
        recognizer.close();
        recognizer = undefined;
      }
    );
```

This is my code that handles stopping the Session.